# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression in inserting data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert a data in the `down_event` table using the data on my `event` table that has more than 1k data but the problem is i'm encountering the more than one row is being returned by my subquery.
Below is my query code:

```
INSERT INTO dashboard.down_event(terminal_id, event_description, down_date, down_time, down_duration_sec)
SELECT terminal_id, event_description, event_start_adj::TIMESTAMP::DATE AS date, event_start_adj::TIMESTAMP::TIME AS time, (SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (SELECT event_end_adj FROM dashboard.event )::timestamp - (SELECT event_start_adj FROM dashboard.event)::timestamp) AS seconds) FROM dashboard.event WHERE event_status = 'DOWN' AND planned = 'UNPLANNED'
```

Upon checking the query. It works for the query below and got all the data i needed in the table.

```
SELECT terminal_id, event description, event_start_adj::TIMESTAMP::DATE as date, event_start_adj::TIMESTAMP::TIME AS time
```

but the problem is when i added my query for extracting the seconds when subtracting the `event_end_adj` column and the `event_start_adj` column. The error seems to appear on this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out why you would be using a subquery.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT terminal_id, event_description,
       event_start_adj::TIMESTAMP::DATE AS date, 
       event_start_adj::TIMESTAMP::TIME AS time,
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM event_end_adj::TIMESTAMP) -
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM event_start_adj::TIMESTAMP)
       ) AS seconds
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE event_status = 'DOWN' AND planned = 'UNPLANNED'
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!